# show user's location with a custom pin on map and in a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

i m showing user's location in a map view(apple map) with custom pin and those same pins are shown in a table view in front of the user name.Each user should have a different pin and if the user name occurs twice then it should have the same pin colour as the previous one.

[image]

This is the table view screen shot and below this table view there is a map view:

[image]

if in the table view "user name" has blue pin then in the map "username's" location shud be shown with blue pin.
if user2 has green pin in table, it should be green in map as well.

the response i m getting is

```
{
    "driver_or_rider" = 1;
    email = "ish@gmail.com";
    isGuest = 0;
    lat = "47.606209";
    long = "-122.332071";
    name = "ish bids";
    "status_trip" = 1;
    "user_image_url" = "http://app/image/1458101010.userimage";
},
{
    "driver_or_rider" = 0;
    email = "arin@gmail.com";
    isGuest = 0;
    lat = "34.052227";
    long = "-118.243660";
    name = "arin John";
    "status_trip" = 1;
    "user_image_url" = "http://app/image/5b3ee2e9fb51c7b20303a95b93bf63b2.";
},
{
    "driver_or_rider" = 0;
    email = "deepak12@gmail.com";
    isGuest = 0;
    lat = "31.968599";
    long = "-99.901813";
    name = "Deepak Chaudhary chaudhary ";
    "status_trip" = 1;
    "user_image_url" = "http://app/image/2197c75dc6b2bbd0ff26008a987781f3.";
},
{
    "driver_or_rider" = 0;
    email = "ish@gmail.com";
    isGuest = 1;
    lat = "31.968599";
    long = "-99.901813";
    name = "Deepak Chaudhary chaudhary 's Guest";
    "status_trip" = 1;
    "user_image_url" = "http://app/image/no-image.png";
},
{
    "driver_or_rider" = 0;
    email = "ish@gmail.com";
    isGuest = 1;
    lat = "41.878114";
    long = "-87.629798";
    name = "shiv Shankar 's Guest";
    "status_trip" = 1;
    "user_image_url" = "http://app/image/no-image.png";
},
{
    "driver_or_rider" = 0;
    email = "shiv@gmail.com";
    isGuest = 0;
    lat = "41.878114";
    long = "-87.629798";
    name = "shiv Shankar ";
    "status_trip" = 1;
    "user_image_url" = "http://app/image/1458129359.userimage";
},
{
    "driver_or_rider" = 0;
    email = "andrew.payasi@gmail.com";
    isGuest = 0;
    lat = "43.65322577127058";
    long = "-79.38318371772766";
    name = username;
    "status_trip" = 1;
    "user_image_url" = "http://app/image/1456821877.png";
}
)
```

this is the code in cell for row at index

int randomNumber = indexPath.row % [imageNameArray count];

```
    NSString* nameStr=[goersInfo valueForKey:@"name"];

    NSArray * nameStrArray = [nameStr componentsSeparatedByString: @"'s"];
    nameStr=[nameStrArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSNumber *indexNumber = self.pinDictionary[nameStr];
    index = indexNumber.unsignedIntegerValue;

    cell.PinImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:index]];
```

this is dictionary where name are stored

```
    - (void)setupPinDictionary
{
    self.pinDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    self.imageNameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"pin2@2x.png", @"pin3@2x.png", @"pin4@2x.png", @"pin5@2x.png", @"pin6@2x.png",@"pin8@2x.png",@"pin9@2x.png", nil];
    NSUInteger pinImageCount = self.imageNameArray.count;

    for (NSDictionary *goersInfo in tableGoersList) {
        NSString* nameStr=[goersInfo valueForKey:@"name"];

        NSArray * nameStrArray = [nameStr componentsSeparatedByString: @"'s"];
        nameStr=[nameStrArray objectAtIndex:0];

        if (self.pinDictionary[nameStr] == nil) {
             indexPin = arc4random() % pinImageCount;
            self.pinDictionary[nameStr] = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger: indexPin];
        }
    }
```

Initially this method is called

```
-(void)doJourneyGoersList:(id)responseObject{

    NSDictionary *dict=[responseObject[@"Count"] firstObject];

    checkLocation=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (dict==nil) {

        return;
    }


    [_messagesButton.badgeButton setBadgeValue:dict[@"Count_Masssage"]];
    [_invitesButton.badgeButton setBadgeValue:dict[@"invite_count"]];
    [_matchedButton.badgeButton setBadgeValue:dict[@"Count_Match"]];


    goersList=  [responseObject objectForKey:@"statement"];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D orginCllocation=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([_tripDetails[@"origin_lat"] doubleValue], [_tripDetails[@"origin_long"] doubleValue]);
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation =[[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate=orginCllocation;
    [checkLocation addObject:annotation];

    tableGoersList=[NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in goersList) {

        NSMutableDictionary *localdict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
        loc=[NSMutableDictionary new];

        [localdict setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
        [localdict setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"email"];


        if ([dict[@"status_trip"] isEqualToString:@"confirm"]) {

            [localdict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"status_trip"];
            [loc setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"origin_lat"] forKey:@"lat"];
            [loc setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"origin_long"] forKey:@"long"];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D location=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([loc[@"lat"] doubleValue], [loc[@"long"] doubleValue]);

             [localdict setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"origin_lat"] forKey:@"lat"];
            [localdict setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"origin_long"] forKey:@"long"];
            if (location.latitude == orginCllocation.latitude && location.longitude == orginCllocation.longitude) {
                //location is origin, skip this since it is already added
            } else {
                MKPointAnnotation *annotation =[[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                annotation.coordinate=location;
                [checkLocation addObject: annotation];
            }
            NSLog(@"check location %@",checkLocation);
        }
        else
            [localdict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"status_trip"];

        if ([dict[@"isGuest"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

            [localdict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"isGuest"];
        }
        else
            [localdict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"isGuest"];

        [localdict setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"user_image_url"] forKey:@"user_image_url"];

        if ([dict[@"driver_or_rider"] isEqualToString:@"Drive"]) {

            [localdict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"driver_or_rider"];

            [tableGoersList insertObject:localdict atIndex:0];

        }
        else
        {
            [localdict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"driver_or_rider"];

            [tableGoersList addObject:localdict];

        }

        //add the objects to the array
    }


    CLLocationCoordinate2D parkCllocation=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([_tripDetails[@"park_lat"] doubleValue], [_tripDetails[@"park_long"] doubleValue]);

    MKPointAnnotation *jauntAnnotationPark =[[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    jauntAnnotationPark.coordinate=parkCllocation;
    [checkLocation addObject:jauntAnnotationPark];

    [mapView showAnnotations: checkLocation animated:NO];
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.region.center animated:NO];



    int count = [checkLocation count];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        coordinateArray[i] = ((MKPointAnnotation *)checkLocation[i]).coordinate;
    }

    self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:count];

    [mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
    [self setupPinDictionary];
    [self.ridersTableView reloadData];

}
```

and this is the code for view for annotation

```
 {
        imageNameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"pin2@2x.png", @"pin3@2x.png", @"pin4@2x.png", @"pin5@2x.png", @"pin6@2x.png",@"pin8@2x.png",@"pin9@2x.png",nil];

            [self setupPinDictionary];

            myAnnotation.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPin]];



            }

    return myAnnotation;
}
```

Comment: where do you get pin image local or server?Find out unique values from JSON, If there any duplication in name add some extra special character to unique value for only showing pin

Comment: If it is coming from server, set tag to your Annotation object and assign every images in viewForAnnotation delegate.

Comment: its not coming from server,i m setting pin image from an array of images

Comment: you want to assign diffrent image for diffrent user name right? can you able find your same name in array of dic?make condition at both getting index and setting your name